# Why am I getting an internal server error?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a REST web service with Spring, but I'm getting a internal server error and don't understand why.
I have a List of DoenteIdentidade's, this is the structure of the DoenteIdentidade

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Highway Ergonomic",
    "dataNasc": "2020-01-10",
    "altura": 31098,
    "morada": "moratorium pixel withdrawal",
    "codPost": "Mississippi embrace Developer",
    "freguesia": "synthesize Idaho compress",
    "nif": 49379,
    "medFam": "Poland",
    "sexo": "Masculino",
    "telef": 3142,
    "telef2": 89576,
    "docId": 63641,
    "nBenef": 47537,
    "nUtente": 31435,
    "numProcHosp": 56327,
    "doente": {
        "id": 1,
        "situacao": "StatusDP",
        "horarioDoentes": null,
        "doenteDiagnosticoSocials": null,
        "doenteRegistosIntervencoes": null,
        "doenteHistMovimentos": null,
        "doenteContactosOutros": null,
        "turnos": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Metal"
        }
    },
    "subsistemas": {
        "id": 3,
        "gidNome": "Small",
        "gidCode": 14001,
        "subSisGrupo": null
    },
    "centroSaude": null,
    "hospRef": null,
    "pais": null,
    "aces": null
}
```

As you can see there is a object inside called Doente, what I'm trying to do is extract all the Doente objects contained inside all the DoenteIdentidade of this list to a List of Doente's.

Here is a snippet of the code I wrote for this goal, for some reason I'm getting a internal server error when I try to add to the List of Doente's.

```
else if(situacao == null && subSistema != null && t == null){
        List<DoenteIdentidade> doenteIdentidades = doenteIdentidadeRepository.findAllBySubsistemasId(subSistema);
        List<Doente> doentes2=null;
        for (DoenteIdentidade doenteIdentidade: doenteIdentidades) {
            doentes2.add(doenteIdentidade.getDoente());
        }
        return doentes2;
    }
```

Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger? it is such an amazing tool to find out what's wrong in your code. Please have a try

Comment: You should have a log inside the server logs. "Internal server error" is just the response it sends to the client, somewhere inside the server it will tell you what internal error actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

doentes2 is null when you are adding your doente. Try instead:

```
List<Doente> doentes2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank  you that solved it, I wish I knew how to mark the question as solved